ros2 parameter dynamic update and node restart
I'm wondering what design pattern, if any, should be followed for a ros2 node that restarts after a dynamic parameter update. The use case is the following:

ros2 node starts and reads parameters from file
Another application or user dynamically updates one of the parameters for the ros2 node
ros2 node is restarted manually or automatically restarts on a crash of the node
ros2 node reads parameters from file. The question is how does it get the dynamic parameter update that was sent previously without the previous agent sending it again.

My guess is that there isn't any common way of doing this but I thought I'd ask.

A parameter change is a service call, that you can answer in any way you see fit, including saving the parameters to a (yaml) file you can later load.
An example is this:
I found this repo which implements it in a working manner.
Essentially like here
dyn_params_handler_ = this->add_on_set_parameters_callback(
        [this](std::vector<rclcpp::Parameter> parameters) -> rcl_interfaces::msg::SetParametersResult {
            return this->dynamicParametersCallback(parameters);
        });

you have a handler that calls a callback like such
CaccController::dynamicParametersCallback(
  std::vector<rclcpp::Parameter> parameters)
{
  rcl_interfaces::msg::SetParametersResult result;

 //Whatever you want to do when any parameter in parameters is changed
 // e.g. dump_to_yaml_file(this->get_parameters, path_to_file);

  result.successful = true;
  return result;
}

once a parameter is changed. I strongly suggest the same thing works in python, too.

Also https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-rclcpp-parameter-callback/ this might be more helpful than the usecase-specific code in my answer.

The problem with this approach is that if the node already loads its parameters from a file when starting there needs to be additional logic to determine not to use that file and load the dynamically generated one instead.
